# Getting "Access denied" error in all the pages of the drupal site 

Tags: drupal

I have just moved site from online to the local , I have used "authcache, cacherouter" caching module , but restoring site in local there are so many data in the cache table and having problem to download and restore those tables so i just created those tables with blank entries in local and now getting "Access denied" error in all the pages , even i am not able to log in in admin and can not access to the admin section.

I have tried so many solutions available on the net but not get success , Can anyone here help me out on this issue . ?

So much thanks in advance..

Comment: Is $cookie_domain set in settings.php?

Answer (score 1):

Several steps to take:

1. Are cookies working at all: Do you get a cookie (check your browser) and is the domain in that cookie correct?
2. Did Drupal insert the session? Check the `sessions` table in Drupal. For evaluation, empty that table (`TRUNCATE sessions`) and check again: is a new entry made?
3. Are there any errors? Check the watchdog (without access to the site, you can either use [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) or read the `watchdog`  table.
4. Does the server or one of its services give you any hints in their log? Check `/var/log/mysql*` and `/var/log/apache/*` for starters.
5. Did you try disabling modules? Disable all modules execpt a few core ones (use Drush, or set the `status` column in the `system` table to 0). Is the problem still there? No? Then toggle modules on, one a time, a certain module will introduce the error again.